# How to get id from text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have value text:

```
{
  "4384": {
    "idRoomSv": 4384,
    "NumRoom": 2,
    "RoomId": 269
  }
}
```

I want to get RoomId. It is return :269.
Can you help me? Thank very much!

Comment: What have you tried? We can't help you if we don't see your code.

Comment: It is a string in a field as: {"4384":{"idRoomSv":4384,"NumRoom":2,"RoomId":269}} . I want get value of RoomId. True rerult is: 269. Are you understand?

Comment: I using Mysql Database?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a recent version of MariaDB or MySQL, you can use the [JSON_EXTRACT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_extract/) function.

Edit: try on your sql client the code below

```
SET @json = '{
  "4384": {
    "idRoomSv": 4384,
    "NumRoom": 2,
    "RoomId": 269
  }
}';
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.*.RoomId');
```

And the result is :

```
    JSON_EXTRACT(@json, '$.*.RoomId')
1   [269]
```

The JSON_EXTRACT function accepts a JSON document for the firtst parameter. The second parameter is a JSONPath expression :

- $ : is the root element
- * : wildcard = all elements regardless their names
- RoomId : value of that field

Comment: i using Mysql.I think it is usefull